# How to read from USB without any driver?

Tags: windows, device-driver

We are creating small system which has GPS receiver and PC. We want to test my GPS receiver, We do not want to go for a driver on the first go. First I would like to test my circuit works or nor. GPS IC has been set to output NMEA  sentence. We want a program which just reads data from USB port and print it on the screen.

Can we write something like this easily ? Do we have any open source tool which will achieve this purpose ?

Platform : Windows 7

Answer (score 4):

All devices need a driver, so I'm going to interpret your question as "how can I read NMEA data from my GPS using only drivers provided by the OS, so I don't have to write my own?"

If the GPS chip has a USB interface, then you should have gotten a driver with it.  But most GPS chips have a UART interface which in your case sounds like it is connected to a separate USB-UART conversion chip.  That conversion chip most likely came with a driver as well, but if not, you could jumper the reset pin of the converter chip, disabling it, and then attach a TTL/RS-232 level converter (available off-the-shelf) to the UART traces and then to your computer's serial port.

Unless you suspect that the driver for the USB-UART converter is causing problems, I wouldn't bother.

Comment: Of course it may be that the GPS shows up as a generic USB<->serial device and you can read from it just like reading from a regular serial port.

Comment: @Paul: True, and this is in fact what should happen (using the driver provided by the USB-UART converter vendor).  It's only if it doesn't (for example, the VID/PID might be customized and then the driver won't load) that he might want to think about bypassing the onboard converter.

Comment: You could have it emulate a keyboard HID (see http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/connect/usb/USBFAQ_intro.mspx#EBEAC) but a serial port is much cleaner

Answer (score 1):

Anything connected via USB is a *device*. Devices require a *device driver*, period.

You might be able to get away with an existing driver built into Windows. This is how USB memory keys work for example - they present a generic device that looks like a removable disk, and Windows already includes the drivers for generic removable disks.

You would need to check the documentation for your device to see if it can emulate a device which already has drivers. Otherwise you must install the company's drivers, or you're out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [libusb](http://www.libusb.org/). You should be able to read the data with that and a little code. (Yes, it's a driver. I take the question to mean "without writing a driver".)

Answer (score 1):

You need a device driver for your device.  Unless Windows already have a class driver for the device.

For USB devices on Windows 7 you can write a user-mode driver, see [UMDF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff561308%28VS.85%29.aspx).