# Reading scanner raw data from usb

Tags: c++, usb, wdk

For example I have a scanner (for photos, documents etc). I've installed its driver (win7). How can I read usb input from this scanner using VC++ (I use vs2012). I've seen many related to usb articles but no one helped me. I've never developed usb software so need help in getting started. I've installed winddk as well. Can anybody show a sample of code (it's not necessary should be a scanner, but USB-mouse/keyboard as well)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What good would it do? The USB data is produced by the scanner with the expectation that the PC has the matching driver. Normally, this format is entirely undocumented outside the company which made the scanner and its driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read from usb port you must use some library for it, such as [libusb](http://www.libusb.org/). Also, try [libusb-win32](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/libusb-win32/wiki).

Comment: Is it possible to do it just using winapi (if I don't need crossplatform application)?

Comment: @amplifier - Since you have a driver of course it's possible.  Any type of file or hardware port can be read using the Win32 API as long as there's a driver installed for that device.  Take a look at the answers to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4683337/how-to-read-from-usb-without-any-driver).

Comment: Yes. I have driver installed. Should ReadFile/WriteFile be enough to read/send data from/to usb device?